# How to see Wireless Network Connection Status in Win10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

In Windows 8, you can open this window by right-clicking on a wifi network and selecting "Status":

[image]

How do I see the same information (specifically speed) on Windows 10?

Comment: btw this speed is -- AFAIK -- only maximum specified speed, not true data stream speed.

Comment: also, what is your real problem? You want to know what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the wireless icon in the systray and select "Open Network and Sharing Center".

[image]

Then when it opens select "Change Adapter Settings" on the left side.

[image]

Then right click on the wireless adapter you are using and select "Status"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's still there.

[[image]]

[image]

I find the quickest way to get there is enter 'network connections' in the Cortana search box.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open network etc.
2. Then WiFi on left.
3. Then network sharing center.
4. Then Wi-Fi in center.